# Как слить скриншоты в один спрайт-файл

Tags: php, ffmpeg, спрайт

Есть код, который разбивает видео по кадрам и сохраняет их во временную папку:

```
// временная папка
$tmpPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../tmp/' . md5(microtime());
// путь к видео
$videoPath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/video2.mp4';
mkdir($tmpPath, 0777);
// вырезаем кадры
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $videoPath -an -y " . $tmpPath . "/%d.png");
```

Как можно выбрать несколько случайных кадров, изменив разрешение на `210x210px` и слить их в один длинный рисунок png?

[image: пример одного png изображения со случайными кадрами]

Comment: Думаю надо использовать GD (библиотека php), правда никогда с ней не работал. И жесткое разрешение 210x210 скорее всего не пройдет, по одной из осей его придется менять дабы пропорции кадра соблюдались

Comment: В GD  создаёшь холст размером с результирующее изображение и в цикле тыкаешь туда кадры с отступом, потом выводишь холст в нудный формат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dst_im: ресурс целевого изображения.

src_im: ресурс исходного изображения.

dst_x: x-координата результирующего изображения.

dst_y: y-координата результирующего изображения.

src_x: x-координата исходного изображения.

src_y: y-координата исходного изображения.

src_w: Ширина исходного изображения.

src_h: Высота исходного изображения.

```
bool imagecopymerge ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h , int $pct )



// шаблонное изображение
    $dest = imagecreatefrompng('vinyl.png');

    // обложка
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('cover.jpg');

    // настройка прозрачности и фильтров
    imagealphablending($dest, false);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);

    // объединение изображений
    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100);

    // сообщаем браузеру, что контент страницы будет image/png
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    // отображаем изображение
    imagepng($dest);

    // очищаем память
    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);
```

Comment: Попробовал. Потребуется в цикле пропустить чтобы наложить несколько изображений. Можно обложку `cover.jpg` перед нанесением уменьшить сохраняя пропорции, `720x480` в `200xYYY`, где `YYY` - пропорция. Не могу найти функции в списке, такая есть?